# Temporary disable reverse ssh tunneling

Tags: networking, ssh, nat, tunnel

I'm setting up my server which is behing NAT and firewall. To get access to ssh i set up a `reverse ssh tunneling` to another sever which has public IP.

I'm a bit scared that it's not secure enough, that this tunneling is active 100% of time.

Is there a way to block tunneling on the public server? I would like to have an option to:

1. Connect to public server SSH
2. Enable tunneling port
3. Connect to tunneled port (to my server behind NAT)
4. Do my job
5. Disable tunneling port

Is that possible?

Comment: Can you explain what are you scared of?

Comment: It looks like a simple job for the public server firewall (allowing/disallowing access to some port). Do you have access to its configuration? Which firewall is it? Which OS?

Comment: @Jakuje I would not like to have ssh port opened to world all the time. It's too risky while we keep private data on the server.

Comment: Then bind only `localhost` (loopback interface). It is the default.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I do not have firewall installed. I was thinking I can somehow disable it without firewall software/hardware.

Comment: it may be possible to disable tunnelling (perhaps not reverse in particular, but tunnelling generally), but if it's a setting in the server then I think  you'll probably or possibly have to restart the server after changing the setting. You say temporary, but temporarily with regard to what.. to time?  Also I think with some things in linux they can be to such an extent one thing, that you may have to and be expected to use many tools to accomplish what you want, even if it's a feature one could argue they should've included and with a good method of how.

Answer (score 0):

If your tunnel is listening on the public server public interface, then you may block/unblock the port on a public server firewall as you need. When the tunnel is not blocked there is no additional security coming from SSH.

---

If your tunnel is listening on the public server loopback interface then you don't need to turn in off and on again; just secure the public router. If it comes to the safety I would recommend this solution (almost, I will explain it below). You will access your tunneled service either

- by connecting from the public server itself

or

- via another SSH tunnel.

The (Linux) command to establish such a tunnel from a third host (like your private laptop) is:

```
ssh <user>@<public-server-IP> -L <portA>:127.0.0.1:<portB>
```

where `<portB>` is the port on which the original tunnel is listening, `<portA>` is the port of your choice (make it at least `1024` because lower ones may be restricted).

Then connect to `127.0.0.1:<portA>`. This connection is local to your computer. On your public server there would be also a local connection to `127.0.0.1:<portB>` so the entire security is SSH security which is quite strong when you use it right (good password/key etc.).

The only flaw I can think of is: *another* user with access (like SSH access) to your public server may connect to `127.0.0.1<portB>` on it. If this is also the concern then you should modify the tunneling solution as explained below.

---

Instead of creating a tunnel leading to your (potentially insecure) service, make a tunnel to the NAT-ed server SSH in the first place.

On the NAT-ed server you will go like this:

```
ssh <user>@<public-server-IP> -R <public-server-IP>:<portB>:127.0.0.1:<portSSH>
```

where `<portSSH>` is the port on which the SSH server on your NAT-ed router listens (typically `22`). (The SSH server configuration on the public router may prevent you from binding to `<public-server-IP>`; in Linux `sshd` it is `GatewayPorts` option, reconfigure if needed.) This way you will have the NAT-ed server SSH available on `<public-server-IP>:<portB>`.

Next make a tunnel from your local computer to the NAT-ed server:

```
ssh <user1>@<public-server-IP> -p <portB> -L <portA>:127.0.0.1:<portS>
```

where `<portS>` is the service port on the NAT-ed server and again you can choose `<portA>` (again at least `1024`). Note you should now use your NAT-ed server credentials.

Then connect to `127.0.0.1:<portA>` to reach the service from your local computer.

The improvement is: there is no open port on your public router leading directly to your service on the NAT-ed router. If you make the service listen only on the loopback interface of the NAT-ed router then it will also be inaccessible from its LAN. This makes the solution very secure (again: with good SSH password/key etc.) and safe to use even with a service that is totally open and doesn't care about credentials.